# SplitLayoutPanel - how to change children width after creation

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt

i need to resize a widget located in the "west" of a `SplitLayoutPanel` after the `SplitLayoutPanel` has been created. I have tried something like:

```
SplitLayoutPanel splitLayoutPanel; 

splitLayoutPanel.getWidget(index).setWidth("30px");
```

but that only changes the widget's width and does not "move" the line that separates the "west" panel with the "center" panel.

Any ideas on how to change the widget's width and make the "center" panel take the remaining place ?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set widget size as follows: `splitLayoutPanel.setWidgetSize(westWidget, 30);` But you have to know the widget at the west.

Comment: I think I've overlook this method. ^^